# Term for emotion-eater

Tags: terminology, vocabulary

What is a term for a (fantastical) creature that **consumes feelings and emotions** for nourishment?

(Google searches amusingly turn up only discussions about "emotional eating" in the sense of people that over-eat when they're depressed.)

Comment: TV Tropes just calls them [emotion eaters](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/EmotionEater). Or you could go with their subcategory thereof - ["psychic vampires"](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/OurVampiresAreDifferent)

Comment: Looking more for an official term, like something with the "-vore" suffix.

Comment: @ Southpaw Hare: I think you will struggle to find an "official" term for such a "fantastical" referent, but half-a-dozen people indexed by Google have used the word **emotovore**, which would probably be transparent enough *in context*.

Comment: @FumbleFingers - darn. I didn't see your comment, I was busy looking. I have the same source for emotion eaters as well. If you post your answer, I'll remove mine. Though I do like your emot(i?)vore.

Comment: @Susan: Your *emotivore* is much better than my *emotovore* (over 250 hits on Google). Add that in and I'll upvote *your* answer!

Comment: @FumbleFingers - you are very kind. :)

Comment: Emotiphage maybe?

Comment: @MiloPrice +1 Yes, why not. Even '(strict) *emotarian*'

Comment: @SouthpawHare *-vore* has no negative connotations. Just for info.

Comment: @Kris I never suggested that it did.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

An [Emotion Eater](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/EmotionEater) is someone who draws psychic nourishment or power from another person's emotions, and will usually do what they can to instill those emotions in others.

They are very similar to [Psychic Vampires](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Psychic_vampire), ankle biters, energy vampires and other fantasy named creatures.

HT to @FumbleFingers for emotovore, which actually produced emotivore, used in [Doctor Who](http://www.kasterborous.com/2013/04/reaction-to-the-rings-of-akhaten/).

Comment: +1 for Psychic Vampire. "Emotional vampire" would very clearly evoke specifically feeding off of emotions.

Answer (score 2):

Try emotional vampire. You may want to read this entry. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Psychic_vampire#Emotional_vampires

Comment: Found this article: http://psychcentral.com/blog/archives/2009/10/27/5-emotional-vampires-and-how-to-combat-them/

Answer (score 2):

The best term for this is psychic vampire. This is sometimes abbreviated psy-vamp (or psi-vamp). Alternate terms for these entities include energy vampire, energy predator, energy parasite, and energivore, as well as psionic vampire, pranic vampire, and empathic vampire.

Answer (score 1):

You mean kind of like an incubus or a succubus? (It's just a thought . . ..)

Comment: That's an example, but I'm looking for a general, broad term.

Answer (score 0):

In contemporary philosophy, there is [the Utility Monster](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Utility_monster). Put simply, he gets so much pleasure from the things that please him that everyone else suffering in the world but him being happy leads to a happier world overall. In this way, it operates as a challenge to Utilitarianism.